# Unix Command to Download from URL to Directory

Tags: unix

Is there a unix command I can use to pull a file from a URL and put it into a directory of my choice?  So I have a URL which if you go to it, a file will be downloaded.  I want to be able to type a unix command to download the linked file from the URL I specify and place it into a directory of my choice.

So if the URL `www.example.com/image.png`. I want to type a unix command to download the `image.png` file, I want to put that file into my `examples/` directory

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried curl and wget as suggested; however, I do not believe the file is finishing downloading. The file I am attempting to download is a .apk (android app) Thanks for all suggestions so far

Comment: Both curl and wget provide progress indication for downloads.

Comment: Yes they do and they say 100%; however, I don't think it is correct.  try for yourself.  I am using the following URL to test: `http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/download/temp/1280424320_ASTRO_File_Manager_2.5.2.apk`  First try with both curl and wget then go to the URL directly and compare the results

Comment: And I've also got an error when trying wget `Connecting to www.freewarelovers.com|50.16.198.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.`

Comment: I suspect the freewarelovers site has set things up such that you cannot directly download the resource using the URL you provided.

Answer (score 12):

```
wget -P examples/ www.example.com/image.png
```

and

```
curl -o examples/image.png www.example.com/image.png
```

both work.

Answer (score 9):

Meet your new friend, wget:

```
wget -O examples/image.png www.example.com/image.png
```

Also

```
man wget
```

for more usage details.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned before, wget is your tool of choice.

If The site is protected with a password (HTTP Basic Auth), wget will give you an HTTP 401 Unauthorized, if you don't provide a user and password. Use this to provide a username and password.

```
wget --http-user=<username> --http-password=<Secretpassword> <yourURL>
```